# Datapoints for MCB characteristic curve

Tags: circuit-protection

I am looking for datapoints for MCB characteristic curve. I could not find any from the web. Is there a way to convert such curve (as shown below) to Excel?

[image: MCB Type C characteristic curve].

Update on 5-Dec-2022

1. Miniature circuit breakers (MCBs) are used to protect final circuits such as lighting, general power circuits, etc. It is related to electrical engineering, especially electrical installation and circuit protection.
2. I manage to find out that https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/ provides a nice but manual interface to digitalize the graphs.
3. I will update the post again once I have successfully converted these graphs.

Thanks.

Comment: If all else fails, those graphs are good enough to convert easily by hand.

Comment: Can you explain how this is a valid site question on electrical engineering please?

Answer (score 1):

If that's an actual proper log-log graph (I have my doubts) there are semi-automated ways to digitize the graph. From expensive (OriginPro) to free web-based sites (do a web search).

If it's not (I suspect not) then you'll have to do it manually to get conformity to the graph.